# android:background hides my text 

Tags: android, widget, nine-patch

I have a widget layout as follow :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/widget"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/widget_bg">
<TextView android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:id="@+id/widgetText"
 android:text="@string/sWaitingForLocation"
 android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
 android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
 android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
 android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
 android:textStyle="bold"
 android:gravity="center">
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

But the text doest appear, like it's hidden behind the background.

My background is a 9patch png.
It does work if I use android:background="android:color/black" ...
Can it be my png ? (created using android tool draw9patch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem : my ninepatch png was messed up.

Comment: How was it messed up? I'm having the same problem

Comment: Don't just accept your answer without explaining what and why it was broken, or at the very least take it down.

Answer (score 3):

This might also be a solution for your problem: [Android background hides child view text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384109/android-background-hides-child-view-text).
Can you say what was the problem with your 9-patch and how you fixed it?

Comment: I guess he didn't set a content area while converting it to 9-patch.

Comment: I encountered the same problem, and solved by setting a content area. thanks @OctavianDamiean .

Answer (score 0):

Possibilities that come to mind:

- The text color isn't the same as your drawable is it?
- there is text to display?

Comment: Quick answer : no and yes :)
Default text color is greyish/white and string exists.
If I remove "android:background="@drawable/widget_bg"" then text is display, wich makes me think the text is _behind_ the bg

Comment: @Choumarin: try it with a default 9-patch such as `android:drawable/menuitem_background_pressed`.