# In a home screen widget no child views are shown, just a root LinearLayout with background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appwidget

I'm designing a home screen widget. Layout is simple, I just began adding a views to it, but the problem is what only the container (LinearLayout, a background frame image) is drawn.

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/widgetframe"
    >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/wgt_1st_row_name"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="Some Name"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Current layout is only one I use, it's defined as initial in widget-provider, neither I change it programmatically via `RemoteViews`.
What did I missed, why child TextView isn't drawn?

UPD: when using color instead of 9-patch PNG as background for `LinearLayout` - everything is drawn correctly.

UPD2: The answer is here: [Android background hides child view text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384109/android-background-hides-child-view-text)

In a nutshell: don't use a 9-patch (or any png??) as background in a `ListView` (or not only in it??). `FrameView` with a `ImageView` as a first layer - is the solution.

Comment: Are you drawing black text on a black background?

Comment: Of course not. I set text to black to see it clearly on white-gray background.

Comment: You need to try the same without colors. The layout is correct.

Comment: Your XML works for me (at least in the Graphical Layout tab of the XML editor) if I change background from your drawable (which I don't have) to #f1f1f1.  Is your drawable an image or something else?

Comment: Damn right, when I use color instead of 9-patch PNG - everything is drawn correctly, black text on a white background. But what is the issue with a png background then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is here: Android background hides child view text

In a nutshell: don't use a 9-patch (or any png??) as background in a `ListView` (or not only in it??). `FrameView` with a `ImageView` as a first layer - is the solution.